# Uso correto do termo "entre"

Tags: gramática

Gostaria de saber como devo empregar este termo na seguinte situação:

Desejo informar para alguém que a idade deve ser maior que 0 anos e menor que 60 anos, assim, a frase abaixo está correta?

> A idade deve ser entre 0 e 60 anos

Comment: Porque não "até 60 anos inclusive"?   Mais simples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O uso do `entre` está correto, mas eu sugeriria um outro verbo, ao invés de `ser`:

"A idade deve *estar* entre 0 e 60 anos."
ou
"A pessoa deve *ter* entre 0 e 60 anos."

Comment: Muito obrigado, sanada minha dúvida

Answer (score 2):

Em relação à intervalos numéricos, este acaba sendo um problema de matemática. Ainda que a expressão "entre 0 e 60 anos" esteja totalmente correta, alguns cuidados devem ser tomados se a pessoa realmente quiser impor alguns detalhes (por exemplo, incluir ou excluir um dos limites do intervalo).

Na prática, pode-se dizer "os números entre 10 e 20, incluindo ambos extremos", o que significa 10, 11, 12, ..., 19, 20. Mas se somente os números entre 10 e 20 devem ser indicados (e esse é o sentido original da palavra "entre"), é melhor ser mais explícito para evitar confusão: "os números entre 10 e 20, excluindo os extremos" (agora sim, 11, 12, ... , 18, 19), ainda que a oração adicional não seja necessária. Uma alternativa à este último exemplo seria recorrer à notação formal matemática: "os números maiores que 10 e menores que 20" (não há dúvida que os números 10 e 20 estão excluídos desta lista).

Uma dica: pense em dois muros paralelos, a uma distância de 3m um do outro. Se uma pessoa está "entre" esses dois muros, ela pode estar em qualquer região entre um muro e outro, mas tecnicamente ela não pode estar "em" um dos muros, ou "dentro" de um dos muros. Assim, a noção de exclusão (dos muros) através do termo "entre" se torna evidente.

Comment: Uma maneira mais concisa de dizer   
`os números entre 10 e 20, incluindo ambos extremos`   
é   
`os números entre 10 e 20, inclusive`

Comment: É verdade, mas já me deparei com situações em que a expressão foi utilizada e a seguinte dúvida do interlocutor foi levantada: "inclusive" se refere somente ao 20, ou a ambos 10 e 20?

Comment: Eu diria que não é nada usual essa interpretação ("inclusive" apenas para o último valor) mas, concordo, é uma interpretação possível e "incluindo ambos extremos" deixa menos margem a dúvidas. Nesse sentido, no entanto, é preciso também especificar se são números inteiros, racionais ou reais.

Comment: Boa explicação a sua @tvovalentin